# Will there be a Stack Exchange 3.0?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0

[stackexchange-2.0](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-2.0) is a thing. Will there be a [stackexchange-3.0](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-3.0)?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why is this relevant? Everyone can call a new version, whether this is a (huge) improvement is more an opinion.

Comment: And we'll have an ability yo wear the hatz always... *rolling up eyes dreaming*

Comment: Personally, I think we should subscribe to Apple's way of versioning. Stack Exchange X would produce a much better acronym.

Comment: @AnnaLear acronym of the year!

Comment: Why do people feel the need to downvote this question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Exchange 2.0 is only "a thing" because of the initial attempt to sell the software/service to corporations.

Stack Exchange 2.0 is name given to the sites that come out of [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) where new sites are born and raised by the community that will use the site.

If there is ever a replacement for Area 51 (Area 52?) then that *could* be considered to be Stack Exchange 3.0 - though that would be stretching things somewhat. The actual process doesn't really matter - just that there is a process whereby sites are suggested and nurtured by the community that will use the sites.